# Using Parsley With Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parsley.js

I am trying to add parsley.js to a rails project to do client side form validation and can't seem to get it working.

I am using the gem for parsley for the rails asset pipline - https://github.com/mekishizufu/parsley-rails

```
gem "parsley-rails"
```

I went ahead and required it in my application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require parsley
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

And then I added the following to the form I wish to validate on

```
 <%= form_for :user, :html => {:"data-validate" => 'parsley'} do |user| %>
```

Which generates a data attribute in the html for the form

```
data-validate="parsley"
```

Then to check for the presence of the address I have:

```
<%= label_tag :current_address %>

<%= text_field_tag :address, nil, :data => {:"required" => 'true'} %>
```

Which renders a text field with a attribute for the text field

```
data-required="true"
```

Yet when I click submit no validation occurs and a post request is made. What else do I need to do in order to get parsley working on a rails 3 form? Much appreciated!

Comment: Did you restart the server after the gem installation?

Comment: I did restart the server yeah

Answer (score 4):

The gem uses Parsley-js version 1.2.3, as 2.0.0 is still a release candidate. Here are the docs for that version: http://parsleyjs.github.io/Parsley-1.x/documentation.html

The attributes are a bit different - the form_for tag should look like this:

```
<%= form_for :user, :html => {'parsley-validate' => ''} do |user| %>
```

and the text field:

```
<%= text_field_tag :address, 'parsley-required' => '' %>
```

Hope this helps.

***Update***
The 'parsley-rails' gem is now using v2.0.

Answer (score 3):

The current version is now 2.0.5 and the docs can be found here http://parsleyjs.org

Using the rails gem you need to now add `data-parsley-validate` to the form and directives like `required` to the inputs.

Inside a rails form I had luck with:

`<%= form_for @post, :html => {"data-parsley-validate" => true} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :placeholder => "Title", :required => true %>`

Hope this helps someone until parsley-rails gets some better links or basic usage docs in the readme. Might be a nice PR...

Answer (score 0):

I got parsley  to work in our Rails application by initializing parsley with

```
  $('#form-id').parsley({ 'data-parsley-focus': 'first' });
```

the 'data-parsley-focus' is an option for where parsley will send the cursor if validations fail.

I included the gem as you did in gemfile, but my application.js loads parsley after the ujs adapter

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require parsley
```